# 2017 last mobile Chrome Upgrade - How Disable double-tap ZOOM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'we used, for long time, this (from Mr Evrim Persembe)  :

```
function preventZoom(e){
    var t2 = e.timeStamp;
    var t1 = e.currentTarget.dataset.lastTouch || t2;
    var dt = t2 - t1;
    var fingers = e.touches.length;
    e.currentTarget.dataset.lastTouch = t2;

    if (!dt || dt > 500 || fingers > 1) return; // not double-tap

    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.click();
}
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart',preventZoom);
```

After last chrome upgrade doesn't works anymore.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: try this : <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />

Comment: Thanks  moein rahimi,
but I need  to scale the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, and the older versions of Chrome (for example v50), the JavaScript works fine.

To use with the latest version I've solved it by using [`touch-action: manipulation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action) into the CSS file:

```
body {
  touch-action: manipulation;
  ...
}
```